# Comma separated prefix list with commas inside

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match a comma separated list with prefixed values which contains also a comma.

I finally made it to match all occurrence which doesn't have a `,`.

Sample String (With NL for visualization - original string doesn't have NL):

```
field01=Value 1,
field02=Value 2,
field03=<xml value>,
field04=127.0.0.1,
field05=User-Agent: curl/7.28.0\r\nHost: example.org\r\nAccept: */*,
field06=Location, Resource,
field07={Item 1},{Item 2}
```

My actual RegEx looks like this not optimized piece ....

```
(?'fields'(field[0-9]{2,3})=?([\s\w\d_<>.:="*?\-\/\\(){}<>'#]+))([^,](?&fields))*
```

Any one has a clue how to solve this?

EDIT:

The first pattern is near to my expected result.

This is a anonymized full example of the string:

`asm01=Predictable Resource Location,Information Leakage,asm02=N/A,asm04=Uncategorized,asm08=2021-02-15 09:18:16,asm09=127.0.0.1,asm10=443,asm11=N/A,asm15=,asm16=DE,asm17=User-Agent: curl/7.29.0\r\nHost: dev.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\nX-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n,asm18=/Common/_www.example.com_live_v1,asm20=127.0.0.1,asm22=,asm27=HEAD,asm34=/Common/_www.example.com_live_v1,asm35=HTTPS,asm39=blocked,asm41=0,asm42=3,asm43=0,asm44=Error,asm46=200000028,200100015,asm47=Unix hidden (dot-file) access,.htaccess access,asm48={Unix/Linux Signatures},{Apache/NCSA HTTP Server Signatures},asm50=40622,asm52=200000028,asm53=Unix hidden (dot-file) access,asm54={Unix/Linux Signatures},asm55=,asm61=,asm62=,asm63=8985143867830069446,asm64=example-waf.example.com,asm65=/.htaccess,asm67=Attack signature detected,asm68=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><BAD_MSG><violation_masks><block>13020008202d8a-f803000000000000</block><alarm>417020008202f8a-f803000000000000</alarm><learn>13000008202f8a-f800000000000000</learn><staging>200000-0</staging></violation_masks><request-violations><violation><viol_index>42</viol_index><viol_name>VIOL_ATTACK_SIGNATURE</viol_name><context>request</context><sig_data><sig_id>200000028</sig_id><blocking_mask>7</blocking_mask><kw_data><buffer>Ly5odGFjY2Vzcw==</buffer><offset>0</offset><length>2</length></kw_data></sig_data><sig_data><sig_id>200000028</sig_id><blocking_mask>4</blocking_mask><kw_data><buffer>Ly5odGFjY2Vzcw==</buffer><offset>0</offset><length>3</length></kw_data></sig_data><sig_data><sig_id>200100015</sig_id><blocking_mask>7</blocking_mask><kw_data><buffer>Ly5odGFjY2Vzcw==</buffer><offset>1</offset><length>9</length></kw_data></sig_data></violation></request-violations></BAD_MSG>,asm69=5,asm71=/Common/_dev.example.com_SSL,asm75=127.0.0.1,asm100=,asm101=HEAD /.htaccess HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.29.0\r\nHost: dev.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\nX-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n#015`

Comment: `(?'fields'(field[0-9]{2,3})=?.*?)(?=,\s*field|$)` [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/t9xs8w/1)

Comment: You updated the question, but there is no `field` string

Comment: Thats right, the first Item was a sample dataset of what I try to do.

Comment: But what exactly do you want to match from it?

Comment: I need to get a grouped result like: (asm[0-9]+)=(.*)

Comment: Why not just like this? `(asm[0-9]+)=(.*?)(?=asm[0-9]+=|$)` https://regex101.com/r/Mmzfjx/1

Comment: This pattern has the comma in the result value.

Comment: @Toby See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207462/5424988) with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern does not work as the `fields` group matches the string `field`

You are trying to repeat the named group `fields` but the example strings do not have the string `field`.

**Note** that `[^,]` matches any char except a comma, you can omit the capture group inside the named group `field` as it already is a group and `\w` also matches `\d`

With 2 capture groups:

```
\b(asm[0-9]+)=(.*?)(?=,asm[0-9]+=|$)
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(asm[0-9]+)` Capture **group 1**, match asm and 1+ digits
- `=` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match any char as least as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is

  - `,asm[0-9]+=` Match `,asm` followed by 1+ digits and `=`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqr89y/1)

Comment: This is working too, but has the comma in the matched value.

Comment: @Toby Well, it is removed now

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be (see [regexr.com/5mg1b](http://regexr.com/5mg1b)):

```
/((asm\d{2,3})=(.*?))(?=,asm|$)/g
```

Match groupings will be:

- group #1 - asm01=Predictable Resource Location,Information Leakage
- group #2 - asm01
- group #3 - Predictable Resource Location,Information Leakage

Conditions:

- This will match everything including empty values

The key here is to make sure that each match is delimited by either a comma and your field descriptor, or an end of string. A look ahead will be handy here: `(?=,asm|$)`.

Comment: The first pattern is nearly what I expect as result. But it doesn't match:

- empty Values
- the XML value (removed =)

I updated my post full a full example string

Comment: Just need to replace + with * in group #3 match. Updated my answer.

Comment: This string is problematic: asm68=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><BAD_MSG><violation_masks><block>13020008202d8a-f803000000000000</block><alarm>417020008202f8a-f803000000000000</alarm><learn>13000008202f8a-f800000000000000</learn><staging>200000-0</staging></violation_masks> ... because it has an equal sign. Care to share context or use case for this?

Comment: Yes, thats the violation details from our web application firewall. It's unluckily send as XML  payload. I have no control over this custom pattern else I have no ability to write a python wrapper to avoid a single regex.

Comment: If you will be always using "asm" or "field", it is possible to use a lookahead.

Comment: It's always asm. The field descriptor was just a short dummy dataset to show what I want and not sharing too much personal details. Maybe in this case not the smartest decision.

Comment: Based on your new string, try this: /((asm\d{2,3})=(.*?))(?=,asm|$)/g

Comment: @Toby That is what I posted as an answer.